# Js on change dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onchange

I have a form that has a hidden text input that gets the user id called `user_number_id` and depending on the value the dropdown called `departamento_drop` gets an options filtered to `retorno1`. The problem is that when I open this form to edit something inside it, the selected option of this dropdown changes automatically and changes the real selected value. How can I keep the selected value selected and make sure the filter can understand that and have to respect it?

```
$("#user_number_id").val(function(){
        var selecionado = $(this).val();
        jQuery.get("<?php echo base_url().'departamentos/filter_departamento/'; ?>"+selecionado,
        function(retorno1){
            var ret1 = '<option value="0">------ N/A ------</option>' + retorno1;
            var ret2 = retorno1 + '<option value="0">------ N/A ------</option>';
            if($("#departamento_drop option:selected").val() > '0'){
                jQuery("#departamento_drop").html(ret2);

            }else{
                jQuery("#departamento_drop").html(ret1);
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after 9 hours of work on it, I done this solution but still I need to find how to remove the selected option from `retorno1` to not be duplicated, and for sure if there is any other idea better please share. thank you

```
$("#user_number_id").val(function(){
        var selecionado = $(this).val();
        jQuery.get("<?php echo base_url().'departamentos/filter_departamento/'; ?>"+selecionado,
        function(retorno1){
            var i = 0;
            var pre = retorno1 + '<option value="0">------ N/A ------</option>';

            var count = $($.parseHTML(retorno1)).filter('option').length;
            var dep_dr = $("#departamento_drop option:selected").val();

            for(i=0; i < count; i++){
            var val_drop = $($.parseHTML(retorno1)).filter("option[value*='" + i + "']").val();
            var text_drop = $($.parseHTML(retorno1)).filter("option[value*='" + i + "']").text();
                if (val_drop == dep_dr){
                      jQuery("#departamento_drop").html("<option value ='"+val_drop+"' selected='selected'>"+text_drop+"</option>"+pre);
                }else if(dep_dr == '0'){
                        jQuery("#departamento_drop").html("<option value ='"+dep_dr+"' selected='selected'>------ N/A ------</option>"+pre);
                }
            }
        }); 
});
```